# Missing files in installation of InstallShield 2011 LE on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-le

I have an InstallShield project (InstallShield 2011 Limited Edition) for Visual Studio 2010. The project is created on a machine running Windows XP (32-bit). It builds an installation package for a C# solution targeted to .NET 4.0 Full profile. However, the same project configuration fails to build installation packages on windows 7. It turns out that the installation of InstallShield itself is different in Windows 7 compared to Windows XP.

When building the installation package on WIndows 7, I get several errors like the following:

```
ISEXP : error : -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011LE\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer\3.1\x86\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' to target ...
```

On Windows XP, there are 3 subdirectory structures in `C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011LE\SetupPrerequisites`:

- `Windows Installer`

  - `3.1`
- `Microsoft .net`

  - `4.0`
- `WindowsImagingComponent`

  - `x64`
  - `x86`

These directories and there files are missing after installation of InstallShield on Windows 7.

If I add the files manually, the Windows 7 machine can build the InstallShield project without problem.

Is this a bug in InstallShield or have I missed some features? I would like to be able to build installation packages both on Windows 7 and Windows XP without having to patch the InstallShield installation itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you right click | download the files from the redist screen.  Only the .PRQ (XML) files are in the InstallShield installer.  The rest are pulled down once as you need them.

Comment: OK, does this mean that those files are downloaded when the ISLE-project is **created** in Visual Studio? If that is the case we need to handle this manually when adding new team members sharing the same Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: A strange thing is that when I uninstalled InstallShield and re-installed it again on my XP computer, the subdirs of the SetupPrerequisites directory were there from start, before I opened my VS2010 solution.

Comment: InstallShield installs the PRQ files to C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2011\SetupPrerequisites.  These are the XML files that define the prereq.  The content for the PRQ gets downloaded to subdirectories in that folder.  If different users are using ISLE on the same machine the content should be available to all users once downloaded since it's a common location.  Also note that if the download fails you may need to run Visual Studio elevated ( Right Click Run As Administrator ) so that ISLE will have rights to download there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still need to do some testing to figure out how we should proceed when adding new machines to our team, but I now have enough information to go on and understand what happens.